# JQuery Mobile reload page on popup close under chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, popup, browser-history

At the moment iam developing a *mobile web app* with JQuery Mobile.
When working with the popup-widget iam struggling with an complete page reload when an specific popup closes. If you test this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rDwE7/5/

Under Firefox, everything is fine. You can go to the next page, click on every button, also the buttons in the popups.

But when you try this under Chrome or Safari-Mobile, you get a page reload if you click on the *Add* button in the header and on the *click me* button in the popup.

The popups will be generatet to  runtime if you click on a button.

```
$(document).on('click', '#authAdd', function () {
content = '<form id="popupForm">\
           <input value="click me" type="submit" id="subDo">\
           </form>';
runtimePopup(content);
});


function runtimePopup(message, popupafterclose) {
var template = "<div id='runtimePopup' data-role='popup' data-history='false'
                class='messagePopup' style='max-width:400px'>" 
                + "<span> " + message + " </span> </div>";

popupafterclose = popupafterclose ? popupafterclose : function () {
    $('#runtimePopup').remove();
};

$.mobile.activePage.append(template).trigger("create");

$.mobile.activePage.find(".closePopup").bind("tap", function (e) {
    $.mobile.activePage.find(".messagePopup").popup("close");
});

$.mobile.activePage.find(".messagePopup").popup().popup("open").bind({
    popupafterclose: function () {
        $(this).unbind("popupafterclose").remove();
        popupafterclose();
    }
});
}
```

To close the popup i call popup("close") when the submit button in the popup was clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', '#subDo', function () {
    $('#runtimePopup').popup("close");
});
```

Comment: `input type="submit"` will cause _refresh_.

Comment: oh... thanks for your quick answer! Iam also using the form tag wrong.

Comment: I had the same problem with a link with href="#" and it was resolved by adding "return false;" to stop it from trying to follow the link.  Not sure why it wasn't causing problems with other browsers too.